# Tif images show complete black

Tags: libtiff

I got datasets from [Cell Tracking Challenge](http://celltrackingchallenge.net/datasets) for deep learning task, but tif images (label images) are showing complete black. Geeqie, Gnome image viewer, and Shutter have been tried.

My configuration is:

```
Ubuntu 18.04
Nvidia Driver 430  
libtiff.so.5.3.0
```

[image: tif image extracted form downloaded dataset]

identify -verbose man_seg002.tif gives:

```
Image: man_seg002.tif
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 512x512+0+0
  Resolution: 52631.8x52631.8
  Print size: 0.00972795x0.00972795
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Type: Grayscale
  Base type: Grayscale
  Endianess: LSB
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 16-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 16-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 262144
    Gray:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 10 (0.00015259)
      mean: 1.94572 (2.96899e-05)
      standard deviation: 2.96685 (4.52713e-05)
      kurtosis: 0.326432
      skewness: 1.30041
      entropy: 0.646021
  Colors: 11
  Histogram:
    160474: (    0,    0,    0) #000000000000 gray(0)
     11764: (    1,    1,    1) #000100010001 gray(0%)
     11548: (    2,    2,    2) #000200020002 gray(0%)
     11724: (    3,    3,    3) #000300030003 gray(0%)
      9411: (    4,    4,    4) #000400040004 gray(0%)
     13268: (    5,    5,    5) #000500050005 gray(0%)
     13211: (    6,    6,    6) #000600060006 gray(0%)
      8112: (    7,    7,    7) #000700070007 gray(0%)
      9023: (    8,    8,    8) #000800080008 gray(0%)
      8280: (    9,    9,    9) #000900090009 gray(0%)
      5329: (   10,   10,   10) #000A000A000A gray(0%)
  Rendering intent: Undefined
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Background color: gray(255)
  Border color: gray(223)
  Matte color: gray(189)
  Transparent color: gray(0)
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 512x512+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2019-09-22T10:10:54+08:00
    date:modify: 2013-11-16T07:41:22+08:00
    signature: 20c7b0ccb92bfd0b783d88426b9955ac7ddb3e25b626fd3b22927cdcecd15788
    tiff:alpha: unspecified
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: min-is-black
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 8
  Artifacts:
    filename: man_seg002.tif
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 21.7KB
  Number pixels: 262K
  Pixels per second: 26.21MB
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.010
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: Aren't they .gif animations? For example: http://celltrackingchallenge.net/files/datasets/PhC-C2DL-PSC.gif ?

Comment: No,tif image is extracted from download dataset